# SAP GUI Macro doesnt work when I had more than one session open at the same time

Tags: vba, session, sap-gui

I had develop a macro which search some information in SAP GUI and copy it in a Excel worksheet, but sadly it only works if I had open ONLY ONE session.

Even if I try to create a new session by code (`session.createSession`), the next steps(the important ones) are done in the first session that had been open before, for instance, it enters a code in a text box that doesn't exist in that screen and as a consequence it appears an error.

I know I can solve this by closing all sessions before run this macro, but I do believe that there is a better option for this. Hope you guys can help me with this.

This is the macro:

```
> Sub SAP()

'Macro desarrollada por Marketing
Dim application
Dim connection

If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
  

End If
Sheets("Carga").Select
Range("A2", Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Sort Key1:=[K2], Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

Sheets("Carga").Select
Range("a2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Consulta").Select
Range("c5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
Sheets("Carga").Select
Range("m2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Consulta").Select
Range("c6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Código y producto
    Sheets("Consulta").Select
    Range("B9").Select
    Sheets("Carga").Select
    Range("b2:C2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Consulta").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'lote y paquete
    Sheets("Carga").Select
    Range("e2:F2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Consulta").Select
    Range("g9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Peso y Unidad
Sheets("Carga").Select
    Range("G2:H2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Consulta").Select
    Range("i9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Entrega
Sheets("Carga").Select
    Range("k2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Consulta").Select
    Range("D9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

'Sheets("Carga").Select
 '   Range("M2").Select
  '  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
   ' Selection.Copy
    'Sheets("Consulta").Select
    'Range("I9").Select
    'Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        

'Copiar todos los valores de las remesas y eliminar los que se repiten
Sheets("Consulta").Select
Range("d9").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("BusquedaSAP").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Eliminar las remesas duplicadas

ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo


'Comenzar la búsqueda de Factura SAP a partir de las remesas

Sheets("BusquedaSAP").Select
For K = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Si no hay datos, parar la macro

If IsEmpty(Range("A" & K)) Then

'Volver a la página de inicio de SAP

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press

Exit Sub

Sheets("Consulta").Select

End If

session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "VL03N"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtLIKP-VBELN").Text = Sheets("BusquedaSAP").Range("A" & K).Text
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'Click en Flujo de Documentos(F7)
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press
'la segunda siempre es la remesa
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          2", "&Hierarchy"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07").Select
guiasider = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2110/txtLIKP-XBLNR").Text
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:2110/txtLIKP-XBLNR").SetFocus
Worksheets("BusquedaSAP").Range("C" & K) = guiasider
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press

'Click en Botón buscar
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[0]").pressButton "&FIND"
'Ingresar "Documento Contable en el campo de búsqueda
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtLVC_S_SEA-STRING").Text = "GT - Factura"
'Dar click en aceptar varias veces
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]").Close
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

'Buscar numero de Factura SAP
facturaSAP = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBRK-VBELN").Text
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBRK-VBELN").SetFocus
Worksheets("BusquedaSAP").Range("B" & K) = facturaSAP
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
'Si es la primera remesa que busque todos los datos
If K = 2 Then
'Click en la lupa

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          1", "&Hierarchy"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subSUBSCREEN_HEADER:SAPMV45A:4021/btnBT_HEAD").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07").Select
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4352/subSUBSCREEN_PARTNER_OVERVIEW:SAPLV09C:1000/cmbGV_FILTER").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4352/subSUBSCREEN_PARTNER_OVERVIEW:SAPLV09C:1000/cmbGV_FILTER").Key = "PAREH"
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4352/subSUBSCREEN_PARTNER_OVERVIEW:SAPLV09C:1000/tblSAPLV09CGV_TC_PARTNER_OVERVIEW/txtGVS_TC_DATA-REC-NAME1[2,0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
'Tomar valor de cliente
cliente = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME1").Text
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME1").SetFocus
cliente1 = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME2").Text
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME2").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_HEAD/tabpT\07/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4352/subSUBSCREEN_PARTNER_OVERVIEW:SAPLV09C:1000/tblSAPLV09CGV_TC_PARTNER_OVERVIEW/txtGVS_TC_DATA-REC-NAME1[2,3]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
destinatario = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME1").Text
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME1").SetFocus
destinatario1 = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME2").Text
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subGCS_ADDRESS:SAPLSZA1:0300/subCOUNTRY_SCREEN:SAPLSZA1:0301/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME2").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
'tomar valor de empresa de transportes
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/shell/shellcont[1]/shell[1]").selectItem "          3", "&Hierarchy"
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
'En esta parte se selecciona la empresa de transporte, pero no todos lo tienen y arroja un error, por eso no se considera
'session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_PR/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN1:SAPMV56A:1021/btnB_PR_ADR").press
'empresatransporte = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME1").Text
'session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME1").SetFocus
'empresatransporte1 = session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME2").Text
'session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/txtADDR1_DATA-NAME2").SetFocus
'session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
'Selecciona el nombre del transportista
transportista = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_PR/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN1:SAPMV56A:1021/ctxtVTTK-EXTI1").Text
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsHEADER_TABSTRIP1/tabpTABS_OV_PR/ssubG_HEADER_SUBSCREEN1:SAPMV56A:1021/ctxtVTTK-EXTI1").SetFocus


Worksheets("BusquedaSAP").Range("d2") = cliente & " " & cliente1
Worksheets("BusquedaSAP").Range("e2") = destinatario & " " & destinatario1
Worksheets("BusquedaSAP").Range("f2") = empresatransporte & " " & empresatransporte1
Worksheets("BusquedaSAP").Range("g2") = transportista
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
End If


session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[3]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[12]").press

 
Next K


Sheets("Consulta").Activate

Range("e9").Select
Selection.Copy

For i = 9 To Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row


If Range("B" & i) <> Empty Then

If i = 9 Then

Range("A" & i) = 1


Else


Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i - 1) + 1
Range("e9").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("f9").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("f" & i).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
 
End If
End If

Next i

Sheets("Consulta").Activate
Range("O16").Select

 Selection.Copy
Range(Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, -4), Cells(39, 13)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
 Range("a9:m9").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(Cells(10, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 8)).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
Range("a10").Select

'application.CutCopyMode = False
        
End Sub
```

Cheers

Comment: Would help you get suggestions if you include your code.

Comment: First, let us know how it came about with your question and the solution before.: Different Script (SAP GUI) Codes for the same process in two different Computers

Comment: ScriptMan, could´t follow those steps that appear when I google it, not sure if it's because I don't have permission (I am not the adminsitrator) or it is just that I am not searching the right way in SAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could test the following workaround:

```
> Sub SAP()

'Macro desarrollada por Marketing
Dim application
Dim connection


If Not IsObject(application) Then
 Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
 Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
 Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If

msgbox "Please select a session within the next 5 seconds"
wscript.sleep 5000
set session = application.ActiveSession
if session is nothing then Set session = connection.Children(0)


Sheets("Carga").Select
. . .
```

This link could also be of interest to you:

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1730563

Regards,
ScriptMan